# Generate list of values from SQL query with a sum less than a certain amount

Tags: mysql

I have a table, "table_one," that contains two fields.  One is a folder path on a file system ("directory_path"), for example, "C:/folderOne", and the other is the total file size in bytes ("total_sz_bytes") contained in that folder, for example, "4235."

I am trying to use a SQL query to generate a list of values, starting from the top of the table, whose SUM of the total file size is less than a certain amount, given to the query (like, 10000 bytes for example).

I have the following query so far:

```
SELECT directory_path FROM table_one where 10000 >= 
(select sum(total_sz_bytes) from table_one);
```

But all this does is return all of the entries in the table if the sum of all of them is less than that 10000 number.  So, if I had three folders in the table, "folder_one," "folder_two," and "folder_three," the query would return all of them if their total file size was less than 10000, but none of them if the total file size was greater than 10000.  It doesn't matter if folderOne + folderTwo was 7000; if all of them put together is greater than 10000, the query returns nothing.

How do I revise this query to get a partial list?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause and, if I understand your question correctly, the following should work:

```
SELECT    directory_path, 
          SUM(total_sz_bytes) as total_size 
FROM table_one
GROUP BY directory_path
HAVING total_size <= 10000
```

Comment: That doesn't work quite right either; that returns all of the values in the table whose individual folder sizes are less than 10,000.  So, if one folder is 5500 bytes, and the other is 6500, if I use "10000," both are returned even though their sum adds up to more than 10000.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more in the way of an example of what you want, something along the lines of:  

C:/myfolder/foo           1000
C:/myfoder:/bar           9500
C:/myotherfolder/foo   30000
C:/myotherfolder/bar   5000
C:/folderthree/foo        1000
C:/folderthree/bar        2000

Comment: so, here's an example: If my table contains three entries, folderOne, folderTwo, and folderThree, each with their own path, and their own value for how many bytes they contain.  Say folderOne has 2000 bytes, folderTwo has 4000 bytes, and folderThree has 5000 bytes.  Their total sum is 11000 bytes; I'm only interested in a list of folders whose total is less than 10000 bytes.  So, the query should return folderOne and folderTwo, but not folderThree, since one + two = 6000.

Comment: This is literally the knapsack problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and, even with n = 3, I don't know of a good SQL based solution to it. If you find one, I'd be very curious to see it though.

Comment: haha, I never though of that, but yeah, you're right, they're very similar!  Although with a slight difference: I don't really care about maximizing the efficiency, I'm willing to just go starting from the top and working my way down the table (so, if folderOne + folderTwo = 6000, and folderTwo + folderThree = 9000, I don't care that two + three is closer to 10000, if I get a list containing one and two, that's fine).

Comment: I don't think it'll make a difference.... but I learn new things all the time. If you find something, I'm definitely curious to see it. But I certainly have no idea what it would be.